# Pull back records that include child records

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to pull back records that include child records for the View I'm putting together. Right now I have a working Linq statement, but it's big, and I think I could make it cleaner.

```
var reqMatsInc = (from rm in db.RequiredMaterial
                    join p in db.Project on rm.ProjectTemplateId equals p.ProjectTemplateId
                    where p.ProjectId == id
                    select new RequiredMaterialViewModel
                    {
                        RequiredMaterialId = rm.RequiredMaterialId,
                        ProjectTemplateId = rm.ProjectTemplateId,
                        RequiredMaterialName = rm.RequiredMaterialName,
                        RequiredMaterialDescription = rm.RequiredMaterialDescription,
                        CustomFormId = rm.CustomFormId,
                        AcceptFile = rm.AcceptFile,
                        RequiredMaterialRoles = (
                        from rmr in db.RequiredMaterialRole
                        where rmr.RequiredMaterialId == rm.RequiredMaterialId
                        select new RequiredMaterialRoleViewModel
                        {
                            RequiredMaterialRoleId = rmr.RequiredMaterialRoleId,
                            RequiredMaterialId = rmr.RequiredMaterialId,
                            RoleId = rmr.RoleId,
                            RoleName = rmr.Role.RoleName,
                            IsActive = rmr.IsActive
                        }
                        ).ToList()
                    }
);
```

Right now the `ViewModel` classes are pretty much mirror images of the Code First class they represent. `db` is my `DbContext`.

Here are some of the `ViewModel` classes:

**`RequiredMaterialViewModel`**

```
public class RequiredMaterialViewModel
{
    public Guid RequiredMaterialId { get; set; }

    public Guid ProjectTemplateId { get; set; }

    public ProjectTemplate ProjectTemplate { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Required Material Name")]
    public string RequiredMaterialName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Required Material Description")]
    public string RequiredMaterialDescription { get; set; }

    public Guid? CustomFormId { get; set; }

    public CustomForm CustomForm { get; set; }

    public bool AcceptFile { get; set; }

    public ICollection<RequiredMaterialRoleViewModel> RequiredMaterialRoles { get; set; }

    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

**`RequiredMaterialRoleViewModel`:**

```
public class RequiredMaterialRoleViewModel
{
    public Guid RequiredMaterialRoleId { get; set; }

    public Guid RequiredMaterialId { get; set; }

    public int RoleId { get; set; }

    public string RoleName { get; set; }

    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

I can just get the `RoleName` for this View; that simplifies it some.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that your ViewModel is almost an identical copy of your entity class is a code smell. ViewModel should represent data as it is to be shown on screen, that means that most properties should be simple types (`string`, `int` and `bool` mostly). Weed them out first, I don't believe you need all the IDs either!

Your repository doesn't do any real projection, so you can get rid of the entire `select` clause. Use eager loading (`Include()`) instead of joins (your domain and/or EF config might need to be modified):

```
var reqMatsInc = (from rm in db.RequiredMaterial.Include(rm => rm.RequiredMaterialRoles)
                  join p in db.Project on rm.ProjectTemplateId equals p.ProjectTemplateId
                  where p.ProjectId == id).
```

Then, have another method in another class (preferrably in your UI layer) map the result to  your ViewModels.

(may I suggest [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) to handle this task for you, it was made for exactly these kind of things).